# Communicate with socket from other module

Tags: sockets, haskell, websocket, server

I'd like to run a websocket server and send messages from another module to it.

So far I have only managed to pass a channel to the module which starts the server. But I'd like to have as globally as `writeFile` which can be called from any module at any time.

Also I'd like to have multiple clients with `sendMessage`. Once a connection closes I assume the thread still stays in the `forever` loop.

*Server.hs*

```
import Network.WebSockets
import Control.Concurrent
import Control.Monad
import Data.ByteString

createServer :: IO (Chan ByteString)
createServer = do
    chan <- newChan
    forkIO $ runServer "127.0.0.1" 8080 (serverApp chan)
    ready <- readChan chan -- wait for client
    return chan

serverApp :: Chan ByteString -> PendingConnection -> IO ()
serverApp chan pending =
    do
        print "Client connected"
        connection <- acceptRequest pending
        writeChan chan "ready"
        forever $ do
            msg <- readChan chan
            sendTextData connection msg

sendMessage :: Chan ByteString -> ByteString -> IO ()
sendMessage = writeChan
```

*Main.hs*

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    client <- createServer
    sendMessage client ("hello" :: ByteString)
```

Comment: What is wrong with explicitly passing `client` around? You have a reference to it in `Main`, so any module called from `Main` could be passed a reference to this.

Comment: This is code is supposed to be used in combination with ghci. So everytime I reload the environment I'd have to create the server again which is a bit annoying. Is there a way to just call `sendMessage` and have it create the server if it isn't already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using an `MVar` with `unsafePerformIO`. While not exactly recommended the the code is neat and simple.

```
createServer :: IO ()
createServer = do
    _ <- forkIO $ runServer "127.0.0.1" 8080 serverApp
    return ()

serverApp :: PendingConnection -> IO ()
serverApp pending =
    do
        connection <- acceptRequest pending
        forever $ do
            msg <- takeMVar channel
            sendTextData connection msg

channel :: MVar ByteString
{-# NOINLINE channel #-}
channel = unsafePerformIO newEmptyMVar

sendMessage :: ByteString -> IO ()
sendMessage = putMVar channel
```

The code is still missing exception handling and it only works for 1 connected client.